# Calculating Cross Correlation

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to calculate cross-correlation between two signals in time and frequency domain.I got a different result for both cases.

```
  time=0:1/1000:2;
  A=sin(2*pi*f*t)+sin(2*pi*f*t);
  Y=randn(1,length(A));
  C1=xcorr(A,Y);
  figure
  plot(C1); 
  FFT_A=fft(A);
  FFT_Y=fft(Y);
  F2=FFT_A.*conj(FFT_Y);
  C2=ifft(F2);
  plot(C2);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by aliasing. Please try below code.

```
clear;
  clc;
  N=4000;
  Fs=1000; 
  a1_normalized_frequency=0.1; 
  b1_normalized_frequency=0.3; 
  a1_amplitude=1;
  b1_amplitude=0.5;
  time=0:1/Fs:4;
  a1_frequency=Fs*a1_normalized_frequency;
  b1_frequency=Fs*b1_normalized_frequency;
  A=[zeros(1,length(time)) a1_amplitude*sin(2*pi*a1_frequency*time)+b1_amplitude*sin(2*pi*b1_frequency*time) zeros(1,length(time))];
  Y=randn(1,length(A))+A;
  Cross_Correlation_Time_domain=xcorr(A,Y);
  figure(1)
  plot(Cross_Correlation_Time_domain); 
  FFT_A=fft(A);
  FFT_Y=fft(Y);
  Multiply_FFT_A_Y=FFT_A.*FFT_Y;
  cross_correlation_frequency_domain=ifft(Multiply_FFT_A_Y);
  figure(2)
  plot(fftshift(real(cross_correlation_frequency_domain)));
```

I've added zeros to your A array to avoid aliasing.

When I plot `cross_correlation_frequency_domain` I used `fftshift` function to align signal order.

Comment: Thank you. Please, if I want to shift A signal by plus/minus 100 sample and plot the correlation how can I do that?

Comment: You mean you want to plot your A signal shifted by 100 samples? In that case, just `plot(A(101:end))`

Comment: Thank you, yes, two times. one plus 100 and one minus 100

Comment: `plot(A(101:end-100))`

Comment: Thank you. I mean. I have to shift A 100 samples before I find cross-correlation then find cross-correlation after that between A and Y then plot the correlation

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: `A_Minus100 = circshift(A,[0, -100]); A_Plus100 = circshift(A,[0, 100])`. I assume you are dealing with row vectors, other wise `[0, X]` should be changed to `[X, 0]`. Afterwards then just run the correlation twice.